# Создание и последующее получение якоря в PDF документе

Tags: c#, pdfsharp

Допустим есть оператор который по средствам штатного PDF редактора добавляет объект в документ, что-то вроде штампа или рамки и сохраняет.
Далее подписывает и заливает файл.
Цель на бэке при помощи PdfSharp получить этот якорь и его координаты c последующей подменой якоря сгенерированным изображением.
Или PDF наглухо отрендерит объект и это невозможно.